# Как сделать обычную страницу архивной

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть кастомный тип записи stories, и страница gallery на которой выводятся превью этих записей. При переходе к записям адрес выходит таким site.ru/stories/post, вместо site.ru/gallery/post. Возникла идее создать страницу архива gallery, что б адрес выводился так как мне надо, но проблема в том, что на странице gallery много другой инфы которую человеку надо редактировать из админки. Не могу придумать как сделать так что б привязать кастомную запись к той странице или же что б редактировать архив в админке

Answer (score 0):

По идее вы можете установить значение

```
'has_archive' => false
```

при регистрации произвольного типа записи и создать обычную страницу с таким же слагом, как и у вашего произвольного типа записи. Таким образом  по той же урле будет доступна ваша страница и вы сможете ее редактированть из админки.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать два действия

1. На лету хуком подменять ссылку для нужного типа поста

```
add_filter('pre_post_link', 'change_stories_link', 1, 3 );

function change_stories_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
        
        $post = get_post( $id );

        if( $post->post_type == 'stories' &&  is_object( $post ) )  {
            
                         return '/gallery/'. $post->post_name;   
        }
        return   $post_link ;
}
```

2. Сформировать новое правило для ссылки

```
add_action('init', 'generated_stories_rewrite_rules' ); 

function generated_stories_rewrite_rules() {
       
       add_rewrite_rule(
           '^gallery/(.*)/?$',
           'index.php?post_type=stories&name=$matches[1]',
           'top'
       );
       
       flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```